# Game thinks mouse button is being clicked continously?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, bgi

```
void runGame(){
    readimagefile("PIX\\Landscape.jpg", 0, 0, 800, 800);
    while(1 == 1){
        moveCharacter();
        //moveMonster();
    }
}
void moveCharacter(){

    int move = 0;
    int size = imagesize(0, 0, 800, 800);
    void *background = malloc(size);
    getimage(0, 0, 800, 800, background);

    readimagefile("PIX\\Character\\down_still.gif",x9,y9,x9+50,y9+50);
    thunderClaw();
    //specialAttack();
    //thunderball();
    if(kbhit()){

    if(getch()== 'd'){
        move = 1;
        }
    if(getch()== 'a'){
        move =  3;
        }
    if(getch()== 'w'){
        move = 2;
        }
    if(getch()== 's'){
        move = 4;
        }
    }

    switch (move){

    case 1://left

        readimagefile("PIX\\Character\\left_r.gif",x9,y9,x9+50,y9+50);Sleep(15);
        x9 = x9 + 5;
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        readimagefile("PIX\\Character\\left_still.gif",x9,y9,x9+50,y9+50);Sleep(15);
        x9 = x9 + 5;
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        readimagefile("PIX\\Character\\left_l.gif",x9,y9,x9+50,y9+50);Sleep(15);
        x9 = x9 + 5;
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        readimagefile("PIX\\Character\\left_still.gif",x9,y9,x9+50,y9+50);Sleep(15);
        x9 = x9 + 5;
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        break;

    case 2://up

        readimagefile("PIX\\Character\\up_r.gif",x9,y9,x9+50,y9+50);Sleep(15);
        y9 = y9 - 5;
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        readimagefile("PIX\\Character\\up_still.gif",x9,y9,x9+50,y9+50);Sleep(15);
        y9 = y9 - 5;
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        readimagefile("PIX\\Character\\up_l.gif",x9,y9,x9+50,y9+50);Sleep(15);
        y9 = y9 - 5;
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        readimagefile("PIX\\Character\\up_still.gif",x9,y9,x9+50,y9+50);Sleep(15);
        y9 = y9 - 5;
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        break;

    case 3://right

        readimagefile("PIX\\Character\\right_r.gif",x9,y9,x9+50,y9+50);Sleep(15);
        x9 = x9 - 5;
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        readimagefile("PIX\\Character\\right_still.gif",x9,y9,x9+50,y9+50);Sleep(15);
        x9 = x9 - 5;
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        readimagefile("PIX\\Character\\right_l.gif",x9,y9,x9+50,y9+50);Sleep(15);
        x9 = x9 - 5;
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        readimagefile("PIX\\Character\\right_still.gif",x9,y9,x9+50,y9+50);Sleep(15);
        x9 = x9 - 5;
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        break;


    case 4://down

        readimagefile("PIX\\Character\\down_l.gif",x9,y9,x9+50,y9+50);Sleep(15);
        y9 = y9 + 5;
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        readimagefile("PIX\\Character\\down_still.gif",x9,y9,x9+50,y9+50);Sleep(15);
        y9 = y9 + 5;
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        readimagefile("PIX\\Character\\down_r.gif",x9,y9,x9+50,y9+50);Sleep(15);
        y9 = y9 + 5;
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        readimagefile("PIX\\Character\\down_still.gif",x9,y9,x9+50,y9+50);Sleep(15);
        y9 = y9 + 5;
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        break;

    default:
        readimagefile("PIX\\Character\\down_still.gif", x9, y9, x9+50, y9+50);
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
    }
    }//end function

void thunderClaw(){
    int mx = mousex();
    int my = mousey();

    int size = imagesize(0, 0, 800, 800);
    void *background = malloc(size);
    getimage(0, 0, 800, 800, background);

    getmouseclick(WM_LBUTTONDOWN, mx, my);
    if(WM_LBUTTONDOWN){
        printf("Left mouse button was clicked!\n");
        #ifdef SOUNDfx
        PlaySound("SOUNDS\\Electricity_Shock_Sound_Effect.wav", NULL, SND_ASYNC);
        #endif
        readimagefile("PIX\\Thunderclaw\\thunderclaw00.gif", mx-25, my-25, mx+25, my+25);Sleep(80);
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        readimagefile("PIX\\Thunderclaw\\thunderclaw01.gif", mx-25, my-25, mx+25, my+25);Sleep(80);
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        readimagefile("PIX\\Thunderclaw\\thunderclaw0.gif", mx-25, my-25, mx+25, my+25);Sleep(80);
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        readimagefile("PIX\\Thunderclaw\\thunderclaw.gif", mx-25, my-25, mx+25, my+25);Sleep(80);
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        readimagefile("PIX\\Thunderclaw\\thunderclaw2.gif", mx-25, my-25, mx+25, my+25);Sleep(80);
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        readimagefile("PIX\\Thunderclaw\\thunderclaw3.gif", mx-25, my-25, mx+25, my+25);Sleep(80);
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        readimagefile("PIX\\Thunderclaw\\thunderclaw4.gif", mx-25, my-25, mx+25, my+25);Sleep(80);
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
        readimagefile("PIX\\Thunderclaw\\thunderclaw5.gif", mx-25, my-25, mx+25, my+25);Sleep(80);
        putimage(0, 0, background, COPY_PUT);
    }
}
```

So this is the code I have at the moment. My issue is that it keeps thinking the left mouse button is being clicked constantly. Therefore it is constantly putting the animation in the top left corner and slowing down character movement. I have tried an enourmouse slew of things to stop this but have not been able to figure it out. Google has not helped either. I just don't get how it thinks I am constantly clicking left mouse button. I believe it is because of the if(WM_LBUTTONDOWN) statement. But even that, I have tried changing it, adding different specifications, moving it, getting rid of it, and nothing works out how I need it to. It just constantly thinks left button is being clicked (even when I got rid of if() statement it did this!).

Could anyone help me out on this?

THANKS!

P.S. I am in Visual studio 2012 and in graphics.h library.

```
void getmouseclick( int kind, int& x, int& y )
{
    WindowData *pWndData = BGI__GetWindowDataPtr( );
    POINTS where; // POINT (short) to tell where mouse event happened.

    // Check if mouse event is in range
    if ( !MouseKindInRange( kind ) )
        return;

    // Set position variables to mouse location, or to NO_CLICK if no event occured
    if ( MouseKindInRange( kind ) && pWndData->clicks[kind - WM_MOUSEFIRST].size( ) )
    {
        where = pWndData->clicks[kind - WM_MOUSEFIRST].front( );
        pWndData->clicks[kind - WM_MOUSEFIRST].pop( );
        x = where.x;
        y = where.y;
    }
    else
    {
        x = y = NO_CLICK;
    }
}
```

Is this what you are referring to as in code of `getmouseclick()`? It is not something I wrote hahah just something I am utilizing.

Comment: Anyone out there have advice?

Answer (score 1):

WM_LBUTTONDOWN is a windows constant and it is defined as

```
#define WM_LBUTTONDOWN                  0x0201
```

so

```
 if(WM_LBUTTONDOWN){
```

will always be evaluate to true.

what you want is probably something like

```
if (getmouseclick(WM_LBUTTONDOWN, mx, my) == WM_LBUTTONWDOWN) {
```

Comment: Unfortunately getmouseclick() cannot be put in an if() statement. Or at least when I try it is always red underlined. So I understand my issue of it always being true so it always does it... But I just don't get how to set a condition so ONLY when user presses mouse should it work. I have exhausted my knowledge of mouse functions trying to get this junk to work! haha.

Comment: Since you did not post the code of getmouseclick, i can't tell you what's really wrong...

Comment: Ok I updated first post with code for getmouseclick(). Maybe there is a different mouse command I need? Idk... I am at a loss at this point.

Comment: ok... i guess you're using borland graphic interface.  You should read the documentation http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/cs1300/doc/bgi/

Try  `if (ismouseclick(VM_LBUTTONDOWN)) {`
and delete the getmouseclick call

Comment: Ooh... closer... But now it constantly animates where mouse is whether I click or not, but doesn't do so until I click. Hmm... I seem to need something that will break the statement upon completion, but I don't know what things to use other than break, which only work in switch statements... and switch statement has failed for me when I attempted to use one hahaha.

Answer (score 0):

```
DWORD result = 0;
result = getmouseclick(WM_LBUTTONDOWN, mx, my);
    if(result == WM_LBUTTONDOWN){ // then left mouse button was clicked and do some actions
}
```